# Deriving via ReaderT

Tags: haskell, deriving, derivingvia

I'm writing the Monad instance for this type using ReaderT and deriving via

```
newtype HIO a = HIO {runHIO :: Set HiPermission -> IO a}
```

I've tried to do it this way

```
newtype HIO a = HIO {runHIO :: Set HiPermission -> IO a}
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad) via (ReaderT (Set HiPermission) IO)
```

but got error:

```
Couldn't match representation of type `Set HiPermission -> IO c' with that of `ReaderT (Set HiPermission) IO c' 
arising from the coercion of the method
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ReaderT` is both a type and a value constructor. For `DerivingVia` to work, the newtype constructor must be in scope, not only the type. That is, you need something like `import Control.Monad.Reader` or `import Control.Monad.Reader ( ReaderT(..) )` or `import Control.Monad.Reader ( ReaderT(ReaderT) )`.  But `import Control.Monad.Reader ( ReaderT )` won't work, because it only imports the type.

Comment: The ghci command [`:instances ReaderT (Set HiPermission) IO`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:instances) lists derivable instances, multi-parameter types are not listed for now so it doesn't list `MonadReader (Set HiPermission)` even though it can be derived.

Comment: @danidiaz I think you should make that an answer. @MariaZ presumably importing the `ReaderT` value-constructor does fix your problem?

Answer (score 2):

A likely cause of the problem is that you are importing the `ReaderT` type, but not the `ReaderT` *value constructor*, that is, the function of type `(r -> m a) -> ReaderT r m a` that builds values of type `ReaderT`.

For example, you might have written

```
import Control.Monad.Reader ( ReaderT ) -- only the ReaderT type
```

instead of

```
import Control.Monad.Reader -- import everything
```

or

```
import Control.Monad.Reader ( ReaderT(..) ) -- import the type and its constuctor
```

But, why is it necessary for the `ReaderT` value constructor to be in scope?

The reason is that [`DerivingVia`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html) relies on [`Data.Coerce`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.0.1/docs/html/libraries/base-4.15.0.0/Data-Coerce.html) under the hood. In the module which defines the instance, we must be able to coerce to the "via" type, in this case `ReaderT (Set HiPermission) IO`.

And, as it turns out, to be able to wrap/unwrap a newtype like `ReaderT` using coercions, we need to have its value constructor in scope. Quoting from the [coerce Haddocks](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.0.1/docs/html/libraries/base-4.15.0.0/Data-Coerce.html#t:Coercible):

> The third kind of instance exists for every newtype NT = MkNT T and
> comes in two variants, namely
>
> ```
> instance Coercible a T => Coercible a NT
>
> instance Coercible T b => Coercible NT b
> ```
>
> This instance is only usable **if the constructor MkNT is in scope**.